# How to send emails stored in MySQL database in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, cron, celery

I am building a web application in `Django`. I am storing all the emails in the MySQL database queue so that the system doesn't slow down while sending those emails.

With `PHP`, I would have configured cronjob to run every minute to query the Database queue and send those emails. With Django, I am not sure, how to do it?

Any useful pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: If you send only one or two emails, it's not slow. And you can still use the cronjob.

Comment: [Django Background Tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as a guess.

Comment: How are you storing the emails? In the view or script where you are queueing them why not send them?

Comment: At times, i would be sending more than 3-4 emails at a time which I found takes few seconds with SMTP. So I am storing in a `queue` table which I want to process separately.

Comment: if you really only want to do it as you would in PHP, you can create a management command in django and trigger this from a cronjob (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/), this works out of box without additional dependencies. for a more complex solution, you can use the celery, but it adds another layer into your solution, so consider that with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this module https://pypi.org/project/django-post-office/
It does exactly what you need. It stores all emails in database and than you can send them using command

```
python manage.py send_queued_mail
```

If for some reasons you can not use that module. You can create your command and run it similarly.